# Chances of rolling a 2 on a die or getting heads on a coin or ace of spades.

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

I know the title is confusing. I was just thinking about this question in my head and didn't know how to word it correctly.

Let's say I have a 6-sided die, a coin, and an ace of spades (not the whole deck, just the one card). And I will either roll the die, flip the coin, or give you the ace of spades for free. But you don't know which of these actions I will do.

*(a) What is the chance you will get a 2?*

*(b) What is the chance you will get a head?*

*(c) What is the chance you will get the ace of spades?*

I was thinking the answer could be one of two possibilities:
The first is $\frac{1}{9}$ for all three because there are 9 possible outcomes (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, H, T, Ace) and each one comes up exactly once.

The second is $(\frac{1}{18}, \frac{1}{6}, \frac{1}{3})$ for (a, b, c), respectively.

Because there is an equal chance of doing each action (so $\frac{1}{3}$ for each), then we apply a $\frac{1}{3}$ probability to each action.

So we would have

*(a)*: $(\frac{1}{3})(\frac{1}{6})+(\frac{1}{3})(\frac{0}{2})+(\frac{1}{3})(\frac{0}{1}) = \frac{1}{18}$

*(b)*: $(\frac{1}{3})(\frac{0}{6})+(\frac{1}{3})(\frac{1}{2})+(\frac{1}{3})(\frac{0}{1}) = \frac{1}{6}$

*(c)*: $(\frac{1}{3})(\frac{0}{6})+(\frac{1}{3})(\frac{0}{2})+(\frac{1}{3})(\frac{1}{1}) = \frac{1}{3}$

I have never taken a probability class before, so I don't have much background knowledge. Are either of these right? If so, why?

**Edit**: Suppose each action (roll die, flip coin, grab ace) is equally likely. Sorry, as I said, I know very little about probability.

Comment: "*Because there is an equal chance of doing each action...*" Where does it say that?  **If** that were true, then the second is correct... however there is not enough information in the problem statement to suppose that.  All it says is "*but you don't know which of these actions I will do*" and it doesn't give us any information as to how he decides which to do. 
 As for the first approach, that is very unlikely that each of the outcomes are equally likely... but if the problem statement were to have explicitly told us that they were all equally likely then it would have been the case.

Comment: In general, you should be skeptical of outcomes being equally likely unless you have *strong* reason to believe they are.  There are two outcomes to playing the lottery: you win or you lose.  You don't win the lottery with probability $\frac{1}{2}$ however.

Comment: If the die is fair and the coin is fair, then your second method is correct under the assumption you stated in your edit.